# Display view over recycleview rows and layout is gridlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recycleview with grid layout manager and i want to display some view over recycleview rows which also can overlap over cells of rows.

And i want to add this view over some specific rows.

Below is what i want to achieve.
[image: Recycleview with grid layout manager]

Can anyone please help me out. 
Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem ? What you have tried?

Comment: @ Piyush I am not getting in mind how i can overlap a view over two cells to recycleview rows.

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` as a parent layout and put that view in it. According to your requirement just hide and show that view for particular row.

Comment: @Piyush but this view is only displayed in one cell bcz recycleview layout inflate for each cell but i want to display view which overlaps both cells.

Comment: Are you searching SnapHelper with the RecyclerView? [SnapHelper](https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Coordinater Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create_new_folder_white_24dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_folder"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It will create a layer above you parent layout.

Comment: keep it inside your main layout